# Is there a photogrammetry software suite capable of applying the same operation on a different set of 2D images?

Tags: images, image-processing, 3d, image, orthophotography

Is there a photogrammetry software suite capable of applying the same operation on a different set of 2D images?

Let me clarify it with an example.

There are a lot of photogrammetry applications which provide the capability to combine 2D images into a 3D mesh. Like this:
[image]

Now, what I want to do is save the computations that are used above to create the mesh from the images. But apply them to a different set of images. That is what I try to visualize here:
[image]
So the actual structure, the white object in the middle, remains the same and is based on the original images, while the texturing/coloring of the object has changed.

(Please forgive my terrible photoshop skills. Also disregard the actual contents of the images/masks displayed here, it is just for illustration.)

In principle this should be possible. All the needed transformations are already computed, however, I want to apply them on a different set of images.

Is there anyone who knows of a software suite capable of this?

If possible, I prefer open source.